# In PrimeNG 14, how do I invoke a function in a child component when its parent p-sidebar opens?

Tags: angular, primeng, sidebar, angular14

I'm using PrimeNG 14 and Angular 14.  I have a p-sidebar with a child component in it

```
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="isDisplayed" [showCloseIcon]="true" position="right">
  <app-add-edit-form [model]="myObj"></app-add-edit-form>
</p-sidebar>
```

In my add-edit-form.service.ts file, I have this

```
export class AddEditFormComponent
  implements OnInit
{
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  private resetForm() {
    ...
  }
```

But when my panel opens, "ngOninit" is not called, and I would like my "resetForm" function called whenever the sidebar panel opens with my child component.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ngOnInit` lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence) only runs:

> [...] once, after the first `ngOnChanges()`. `ngOnInit()` is still called even when `ngOnChanges()` is not (which is the case when there are no template-bound inputs).

So most probably your component is not being destroyed/recreated when the `p-sidebar` is hidden/shown. `ngOnInit()` is called the first time the component is added to the template and then never again.

---

There are two ways you could call your `resetForm()` method when the `p-sidebar` opens:

1. Using a [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) to access the instance of `<app-add-edit-form>` from which `resetForm()` could be made available:

```html
<p-sidebar (onShow)="addEditForm.resetForm()">
  <app-add-edit-form #addEditForm></app-add-edit-form>
</p-sidebar>
```

```js
export class AddEditFormComponent {
  
  // Note this must be public to be accessible in the template above.
  public resetForm() {
    ...
  }
}
```

2. Passing the variable you're using to show/hide the `p-sidebar` to your `<app-add-edit-form>` as an `@Input` and using the `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle hook to detect when to reset your form.

```html
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="isDisplayed">
  <app-add-edit-form [showing]="isDisplayed"></app-add-edit-form>
</p-sidebar>
```

```js
export class AddEditFormComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() showing: boolean;  

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.showing
        && changes.showing.previousValue === false
        && changes.showing.currentValue === true) {
      this.resetForm();
    }
  }

  // Note this can be private again.
  private resetForm() {
    ...
  }
}
```

---

I don't recommend it, but there technically is a third way that most closely matches your approach. It will, however, involve the overhead of destroying/recreating the component each time the `p-sidebar` changes state:

3. Using the [`ngIf` structural directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) to destroy/recreate your component when the variable you're using to show/hide the `p-sidebar` changes:

```html
<p-sidebar [(visible)]="isDisplayed">
  <app-add-edit-form *ngIf="isDisplayed"></app-add-edit-form>
</p-sidebar>
```

```js
export class AddEditFormComponent implements OnInit {

  // This is now called each time the sidebar opens
  // because this component is recreated each time.
  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  private resetForm() {
    ...
  }
}
```